# Simple regex crashing android, works fine in iOS

Tags: javascript, android, regex, react-native

In my react native app, I'm using this regular expression to strip non-unicode characters from strings.

```
/[\u{0080}-\u{FFFF}]/gu
```

It works fine in React Native, but the app will fail to start in android...

Any ideas?

Comment: Try `/(?:[\x80-\uD7FF\uE000-\uFFFF]|[\uD800-\uDBFF](?![\uDC00-\uDFFF])|(?:[^\uD800-\uDBFF]|^)[\uDC00-\uDFFF])/g`

Comment: If you use the regex in `replaceAll`, I think you can use `.replaceAll("[^\u0080-\uFFFF]", "")` / `.replaceAll("[^\\u0080-\\uFFFF]", "")` should work.